# how to calculate marginal distribution of continuous random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

The two continuous random variables X and Y are jointly distributed as

$f(x,y) = 24x^2y(1-x)$

for both x and y are greater than and equal to 0 and less than equal to 1 and 0 elsewhere.

calculate the marginal distributions of X and Y

Did you mean f(x,y) to be edited on?

Comment: Say what? You need to clarify the equation for us? :)

Comment: $f_X(x)=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy$ and $f_Y=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx$. Eventually do it.